# How to combine 2 Java classes?

Tags: java, php, android, database, android-activity

I am a newbie at programming. I am trying to combine two activities such that NewProductActivity will carry out the functions in CameraActivity. Both uses a link which directs it to a php page to upload the data into the server database. Please help.

**CameraActivity.java**

```
package sp.com;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private TextView messageText;
    private Button uploadButton, btnselectpic;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    public static final String cameraUrl = "android.intent.extra.CAMERA_URL";

    private String upLoadServerUri = null;
    private String imagepath=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_activity);

        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        btnselectpic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
        imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);

        btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        //upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.0.100/incidentreport2/UploadToServer.php";
        upLoadServerUri = "http://172.20.10.3/incidentreport2/UploadtoServer.php";

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(arg0==btnselectpic)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
        }
        else if (arg0==uploadButton) {

             dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CameraActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
             messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {

                      uploadFile(imagepath);

                 }
               }).start();     
        }

    } 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath(); 

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);

        }
    }
         public String getPath(Uri uri) {
                String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


          String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

               dialog.dismiss(); 

               Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+imagepath);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
                   }
               }); 

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                             + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                      +" F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                                messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewProductActivity.class);
                                i.putExtra(cameraUrl, imagepath);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog.dismiss();       
              return serverResponseCode; 

           } // End else block 
         }


}
```

**CreateNewProduct.java**

```
package sp.com;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputLocation;
    EditText inputDesc;
    String reportType;
    RadioGroup reportTypeGroup;

    public static final String cameraUrl = "android.intent.extra.CAMERA_URL";
    static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Test";
    Uri fileUri;
    ImageView ImagePreview;
    Button btnCapturePicture;
    String cameraIMG;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://172.20.10.3/incidentreport2/create_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            cameraIMG = extras.getString(cameraUrl);
        }

        // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputLocation);
        inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        //Radio Button
        reportTypeGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.typeOfReport);
//      reportType = (RadioButton) reportTypeGroup.findViewById(reportTypeGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()); 
        reportType = "";

        //Camera
        ImagePreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImagePreview);
        btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });     

        btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CameraActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                finish();           

                //captureImage();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
        class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Report..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            switch (reportTypeGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {

            case R.id.hazard:
                reportType = "Hazard";
                break;

            case R.id.incident:
                reportType = "Incident";
                break;

            default:
                reportType = "Unknown";
                break;
            }

            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String location = inputLocation.getText().toString();
            String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();
            String type = reportType.toString();
            String image = cameraIMG.toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", location));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", image));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat for response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

How can i put implement `CameraActivity` to `NewProductActivity`, so that I can use the same layout? Also, it is difficult for me because these two activities use two different `urls`. I can combine the two `urls` to one so that it is easier but I do not know how to replace the url used in CameraActivity.

I want to insert into the `database`, the name, type, location, description and also the uploaded image. The uploaded image link is only known in the `php` file. So if I combine both activities, I can use one `php` file to carry out the inserting because only the `php` file has the image link.

Comment: Do you just wanna combine both due to one Layout?? then why to make two activity ?

Comment: I need to combine the urls too because camera actvitity will be uploading an image, NewProductActivity will be inserting all the data including the uploaded image.

Comment: I am really not getting your requirement

Comment: You DON'T want to do that! Please no! Don't put server stuff on the activity, because the activity should ONLY handle UI stuff, and maybe other calls! Make other classes in order to do what you want, and access them statically.

Comment: The urls are actually PHP files where NewProductActivity executes the inserting to the database and CameraActivity just uploads an image. I will be combining the PHP files into the one where the php file that inserts data into the database, so that i can insert variables as well as the uploaded image link into the database as a single column.

Comment: transform each activity into a fragment (not very difficult) then you can put both fragments into one activity. Read google dox n tutorial about fragments.

Comment: @AndreaGoh Your requirement is unclear, can you please explain it with simple words and concept wise please?

Comment: @AndreaGoh you can contact me on my email pratikdasa@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using

```html
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=mobile_no" + lineEnd); // name=mobile_no so you have to get PHP side using mobile_no
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(mobile_number); // mobile_no is String variable
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

And this is my final code, it inserts my image along with parameters to the database perfectly :)

NewProductActivity.java

```html
package sp.com;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewProductActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 private EditText inputName;
 private EditText inputLocation;
 private EditText inputDesc;
 String reportType;
 private RadioGroup reportTypeGroup;
 
    private TextView messageText;
    private Button uploadButton, btnselectpic;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    //String userId, profileDisplayName, gender, cityId, mobile,
          //  isMobileVerified;
    private String upLoadServerUri = null;
    private String imagepath = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

        uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateReport);
        messageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        btnselectpic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);

        btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.0.105/incidentreport2/create_product.php";
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (arg0 == btnselectpic) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
        } else if (arg0 == uploadButton) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(NewProductActivity.this, "",
                    "Uploading file...", true);
            messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    uploadFile(imagepath);

                }
            }).start();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath();

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" + imagepath);

        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

            dialog.dismiss();

            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + imagepath);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Source File not exist :" + imagepath);
                }
            });

            return 0;

        } else {
            try {       
          // Edit Text
          inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
          inputLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputLocation);
          inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);
          
          //Radio Button
          reportTypeGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.typeOfReport);
          reportType = "";
          
       switch (reportTypeGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {

       case R.id.hazard:
        reportType = "Hazard";
        break;
        
       case R.id.incident:
        reportType = "Incident";
        break;
        
       default:
        reportType = "Unknown";
        break;
       }
         
                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\""
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(inputName.getText().toString());
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=location"
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(inputLocation.getText().toString());
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=description"
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(inputDesc.getText().toString());
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=type"
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(reportType.toString());
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                          + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                 
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
                InputStream urlInputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                String json = null;
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(urlInputStream, "iso-8859-1"),
                            8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    urlInputStream.close();
                    json = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Buffer Error",
                            "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }
                JSONObject jObj;
                // try parse the string to a JSON object
                try {
                    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }

                Log.d("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
                Log.d("content",
                        "HTTP Response content is : " + json.toString() + ": "
                                + serverResponseCode);

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                    + " F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(NewProductActivity.this,
                                    "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                // close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                ex.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messageText
                                .setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                        Toast.makeText(NewProductActivity.this,
                                "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                        Toast.makeText(NewProductActivity.this,
                                "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                        "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;

        } // End else block
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the good approach is to split the network related operations into a separate class and use Observer pattern in Activity to get notified when the network operation has completed.